# Exibir filtragem em java usando banco de dados, não aparece listagem completa

Tags: java, postgresql, programação-funcional

Estou tentando filtrar dados do postgresSql, que vem de uma tabela.

Porem ele está retornando apenas 1 valor, ao invés de todos os resultados com o valor solicitado.
Existem 10 resultados com o nome SESAU , porem ele está exibindo apenas 1 dos 10.

Abaixo código

```java
public Maquinas getBysetor(String setor) {
        Maquinas maquinas = new Maquinas();


        try (Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnectionToPostgres()) {

            PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM maquinas WHERE setor=?");
            pstm.setString(1, setor);

            ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                maquinas.setPat_nti(rs.getInt("pat_nti"));
                maquinas.setUltimo_CH(rs.getInt("ultimo_CH"));
                maquinas.setMarca(rs.getString("marca"));
                maquinas.setUltimo_laudo(rs.getString("ultimo_laudo"));
                maquinas.setSetor(rs.getString("setor"));
                maquinas.setData_de_entrada(rs.getDate("data_de_entrada"));

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return maquinas;
    }
}
```

AREA DE PARA EXIBIR NO CONSOLE :

```java
public class Consultar_setor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

          maquinas.DAO.maquinasDAO maquinasDAO = new maquinasDAO();
        Maquinas maquinasconsult = maquinasDAO.getBysetor("SESAU");
        System.out.println(maquinasconsult);
    }
```

RESULTADO EXBIDO

```
Maquinas {  pat_nti = 49591, ultimo_CH = 70699, marca = 'Accept', ultimo_laudo = 'Placa-mae', setor = 'SESAU', data_de_entrada = 2021-09-08}
```

deveria sair mais 10 resultados...

Answer (score 0):

No método principal você cria apenas uma instância:

```java
Maquinas maquinas = new Maquinas();
```

...e para cada resultado retornado você sempre seta por cima do anterior.

```java
// sempre usa a mesma referência do mesmo objeto maquinas
maquinas.set...
```

Teria várias formas de resolver o problema.

Uma delas é criar uma lista e ir adicionando objetos a sua lista.

Outra seria ter um print dentro do próprio loop dos objetos retornados.